# MySQL Workbench Loading (super slow)

Tags: mysql, sql

i am currently studying/learning database using mysql but recently i have this problem(loading problem to exact)

whenever i tried to run a very simple (check current date) it loads very very very load(i not sure how long it can go on because i just force quit it) but i do notice this when i click server status and when i compare with one of my friend connection status the difference is huge. on the 'loading/load' bar thingy i have roughly like 3-4.93(ping or whatever you call it) & under my '' connection '' i have 4(not sure if this related to the problem i facing) while my friend 'loading/load' ping doesn't even hit 1 like probably 0.90 or less than that or something so i was wondering if anyone ever face this issue? please kindly help because of this problem i cannot do any of my project.

i will do a screenshot of it when i reach home(just in case if my post is unclear)

sorry, and kindly please advise the newbie!

Comment: Please provide more information and be more specific about problem. Thanks

Comment: Where is the DB actually running? Compare PING roundtrip between yours and your fields computer against the computer running the DB. Compare both computers (memory CPU, etc.). Reboot your computer and retry... There are so many thing you can check before posting a question here...